# Pass variable from within PHP function

Tags: php, function, variables, return, unlink

I'd like to report how many files get deleted from a function that I'm running within php via a cron task.

Current codes is as follows:-

```
<?php

function deleteAll($dir) {
    $counter = 0;
    foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) {
        if(is_dir($file)) {
            deleteAll($file); }
        else {
            if(is_file($file)){
// check if file older than 14 days
                if((time() - filemtime($file)) > (60 * 60 * 24 * 14)) {
                    $counter = $counter + 1;
                    unlink($file);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}   

deleteAll("directory_name");

// Write to log file to confirm completed
$fp = fopen("logthis.txt", "a");
fwrite($fp, $counter." files deleted."."\n");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

That makes sense to me with a VBA background, but the counter returns null I think when written to my custom log file at the end.  I presume there is some restriction on a shared hosting site of being able to declare the variable globally or similar?

Appreciate any help!  It's not the end of world if I can't count the deleted files, but it would be nice to log the output in the format I've chosen.

Comment: Have the function `return $counter`.  Right now you're dealing with a scope issue where the `$counter` used in your `fwrite()` call is not the same one as inside of your function.

Comment: Simply a scope issue. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631962/php-variable-scope) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesnt work due to scopes. In your example `$counter` only exists inside your function.

```
function deleteAll($dir):int {
    $counter = 0; // start with zero
    /* Some code here */
    if(is_dir($file)) {
        $counter += deleteAll($file); // also increase with the recursive amount
    }
    /* Some more code here */
    return $counter; // return the counter (at the end of the function
}

$filesRemoved = deleteAll("directory_name");
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to send back more info, eg 'totalCheck'  etc, you can send back an array of info:

```
function deleteAll($dir):array {
    // All code here
    return [
        'counter' => $counter,
        'totalFiles' => $allFilesCount
    ];
}
$removalStats = deleteAll("directory_name");
echo $removalStats['counter'].'files removed, total: '.$removalStats['totalFiles'];
```

---

<sub>There are other solutions like 'pass-by-reference', but you [dont want those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479073/when-is-it-good-to-use-pass-by-reference-in-php).</sub>

Comment: An alternate following some PHP functions: `function deleteAll($dir, &$counter)` then call as `deleteAll("directory_name", $filesRemoved);` But I would only use this if the function needs to return something else.

Comment: And even then I'd change the function so I dont have to reference. IMO it's a code smell.

Comment: Thanks all - rapid respones!  Think I've got my head around that, just a different concept to VBA on the basis of scope where you can't declare variables I suppose.

Comment: Hmmm.  Still having issues with this.  In my code, I've amended to call the funciton with "$filesRemoved = deleteAll("dir_name"); and added "return $counter; at the end of the "if" which tests the files age.  But this bails out on me.  If I add "return $counter" to the final sub clause of the if statement, no error is thrown but it just returns "0".

Comment: @Martijn So I've amended my code to add as per your first suggestion 'return $counter' but all I'm getting returned is the default value I'm setting '$counter' to at the beginning.  I can output the incremental count within the if statement, but it isn't being sent at the end.  I'm clearly doing something daft, but can't quite see it!!

Comment: In PHP, if you return, all following code wont be excuted. You want to put the return before the final closing bracket, at the end of the function

Comment: @Martijn - think I've unpicked my issue - because the function is recursive and calls itself to iterate through the folders and subfolders, `$counter` gets reset each time as it only has scope within that function.  So I can append the count to the log as it deletes each file, and can see it incrementing properly.  But then every time it moves onto a new folder it resets back to 0 as each new folder prompts a new instance of that function.  Will have to think around that a little!!  Thanks for your help, it confirmed I was putting the `return` in the correct place.

Comment: Ah, recursiveness. I'll update my answer just a bit to provide that solution

Comment: @Martijn Wondering if the counter set to zero at the beginning is potentially a problem for the recursiveness in your revised answer?  Won't `$counter = 0` be executed on each recursion?

Comment: Yes you are correct. But thát `$counter` only has the value set to zero for thát itteration.